# Problem with c++ code, generating hash correctly from argon2id

Tags: c++, encryption, project

This piece of c++ code is returning argon2 in HEX format

```
d340619e582c86bbb852f02152aa8961ce806c664f26d5e19a48affaadcdd390a078a5c0a626b11770ec6bdf46e456d278cb9056b575158613e95d9dc08ceb8d
```

I need to return the argon2id hash like this

```
$argon2id$v=19$m=16,t=2,p=1$TVlTQUxUSVNDT09M$00Bhnlgshru4UvAhUqqJYc6AbGZPJtXhmkiv+q3N05CgeKXApiaxF3Dsa99G5FbSeMuQVrV1FYYT6V2dwIzrjQ
```

Its using MYSALTISCOOL as a word for salting, Parallelism Factor 1, Memory Cost 16, Iterations 2, Hash Length 64.

The compiler is working with this code but when I trie to implement or convert the HEX to argon hash it justs get bugged somewhere.

Here is the code excert

```
//
// ARGON2 PASSWORD CRYPT BEGIN
//
std::string DBManager::Argon2PasswordHash(const char* password) {
    std::string returnStr = "";

    // Salt and parameters
    uint8_t salt[] = "MYSALTISCOOL";
    uint32_t saltlen = strlen((char*)salt);

    // Password and its length
    uint8_t* pwd = (uint8_t*)strdup(password);
    uint32_t pwdlen = strlen((char*)pwd);

    // Hashing
    uint8_t hash[EArgon2::HASH_LENGTH];
    int ret = argon2id_hash_raw(
        EArgon2::TIME_COST, EArgon2::MEMORY_COST, EArgon2::PARALLELISM,
        pwd, pwdlen, salt, saltlen, hash, EArgon2::HASH_LENGTH
    );
    free(pwd);

    if (ret != ARGON2_OK) {
        // Handle error
        std::cerr << "Error generating Argon2 hash: " << ret << std::endl;
        return returnStr;
    }

    // Encode the hash
    char encodedHash[encodedlen(
        EArgon2::TIME_COST, EArgon2::MEMORY_COST, EArgon2::PARALLELISM,
        saltlen, EArgon2::HASH_LENGTH, Argon2_id
    ) + 1];

    ret = argon2id_hash_encoded(
        EArgon2::TIME_COST, EArgon2::MEMORY_COST, EArgon2::PARALLELISM,
        pwd, pwdlen, salt, saltlen, EArgon2::HASH_LENGTH,
        encodedHash, sizeof(encodedHash)
    );

    if (ret != ARGON2_OK) {
        // Handle error
        std::cerr << "Error encoding Argon2 hash: " << ret << std::endl;
        return returnStr;
    }

    returnStr = encodedHash;

    return returnStr;
}
//
// ARGON2 PASSWORD CRYPT END
//
```

I tried to use std::vector<uint8_t>, and other ways.

Comment: Do you want the raw hash or the encoded hash? Is there a reason you aren't calling argon2id_hash_encoded?

Comment: The process simply returns the hash in HEX. The expectation is a result of the hash encoded in base64 and expressed in this way: `$key-derivation-func$v=?$memory$iterations$parallelism$hash[base64encoded$`. I don’t know what `v` represents. But seeing that the expectation requires base64 encoding, use base64 encoding over HEX. This your expectation is what I have seen in some libraries like Django.

Comment: I need the result like this

$argon2id$v=19$m=16,t=2,p=1$TVlTQUxUSVNDT09M$00Bhnlgshru4UvAhUqqJYc6AbGZPJtXhmkiv+q3N05CgeKXApiaxF3Dsa99G5FbSeMuQVrV1FYYT6V2dwIzrjQ

Comment: `v` is version of argon2id

Comment: It seems like the first comment gave you the answer, but it was ignored.

Comment: I think I got it, Im trying to implement it later, thank you